# Session Variable Size Increase in PHP Mysql Codeigniter app

Tags: php, mysql, session, variables

I've had an issue that I thought was tinyMCE, then my db, now I think it's my session var size.  I have a php app connected to a mysql db.  There is a field that has 2900+ chars in it.  When I load the page, the area that should display this text is either completely missing or once I remove a large chunk of the text from the db I can see the reduced text.  While debugging, I saw the var that is holding the intro text [session->userdata->ACCOUNT_INTRO_TEXT] saids 1024 (2963) for length.  So the session var length/size is 1024, but 2963 are being sent, so var is truncating.  How to I increase the size of this session var?

Comment: Please post the code which accesses the data, and maybe the relevant portion of the database schema.

Comment: Why does this need to be in the session?

Comment: Hi Paul, this is an inherited app, so I need to keep as much of the original structure in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help those who come behind this:

FINALLY! FINALLY discovered what was wrong -  there is a size limitation for the amount of data stored in the session object.  And as per RFC 2109 this size limit is 4KB.  THat was it.  I knew I was hitting some limit somewhere, finally figured it out where it was. Had to re-write some code so I could pull only these text section and not rely on the data stored in the session.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs probably because your session is being stored in the cookie (which is indeed limited to 4k), as this is the default behavior for CodeIgniter sessions.
Note that CodeIgniter sessions are not the same as the PHP sessions.

I used to put the session in the database, as the CodeIgniter manual recommends (see section entitled "Saving Session Data to a Database"):

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

That would probably solve your problem, and you would gain better security with the session validation mechanism.
Hope it helps!